# How to import Chromium Browser-Data to Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

In Chrome under **Settings -> Personal Stuff**, I am given the option to 'Import Data from Another Browser..'. However Chromium is not displayed as an option...

[image]

Is the only way to do this to sync with my Google account? Is there an offline way to copy over the data? Or a workaround that does not require I have a Google account to sync to?

Comment: Note: That is not three separate questions; rather the same question posed in three different ways.

Comment: That's not quite correct. As mentioned by "John Salvatier", Chromium is started **instead of** Google Chrome afterwards. The better option is to replace your symlink command: `ln -s ~/.config/chromium/Default ~/.config/google-chrome/Default` (after deleting/backuping the Default-folder).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Do a copy of your `~/.config/chromium` directory to your `~/.config/google-chrome` directory.

You can also do a symlink, like this:

`ln -s ~/.config/chromium ~/.config/google-chrome`

That will use the chromium config as the "authoritative"/"master" config directory, with chrome just looking into chromium.

It's also a wise decision to quit Chromium and/or Chrome so that you don't have any issues with config directories.

Comment: In order to get the symlink to do anything, I had to delete ~/.config/google-chrome. However, that subsequently made starting chrome simply start chromium.

Comment: Symlinking works just fine for me :-)

Comment: I don't know why the symlink didn't do it for me, but closing the browser and copying all the config files from chromium to google-chrome worked.

Comment: @iyrin Is it possible you did the symlink "backwards"?

Comment: The path may be different for snap, e.g. `~/snap/chromium/821/.config/chromium`.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is  almost the same for all browsers.

In Chromium, go to **Bookmarks/Bookmarks Manager** (**NOT** to "Import bookmarks and settings")- "Organize": "Export bookmarks to HTML file" and save your bookmarks as html file. Then in Google Chrome (or very similarly in any other browser) go to **Bookmarks manager** and in the same way import bookmarks from  the HTML file that you just saved. Save your bookmarks as html from time to time and import them when you need them in new browsers.

Shortcut to access bookmarks manager: **Shift-Ctrl-O**.

Comment: This is only for bookmarks. I want to copy all browser data including plugin data and settings.

Comment: I think there is no built-in way to transfer all the rest, just the possibility of transferring between the config directories as jrg said in his answer.

Comment: yup, which is why it is the accepted answer:P I +1 yours because it i'm sure someone will stumble here while trying to only copy bookmarks :P cheers!

Answer (score 1):

1. Find out your source directory, typically that’s one of:

   - `srcdir=~/.config/chromium`
   - `srcdir=~/snap/chromium/common/chromium`
2. If you’re planning to continue to use both profiles and want to share them, use a symlink (note you cannot use both simultaneously, only one browser can be running at a time). If no sharing is necessary make a copy or move the directory. 
   Make sure, `~/.config/google-chrome` doesn’t yet exist (`rm -r ~/.config/google-chrome` if necessary), then:

   - Symlink: `ln -s $srcdir ~/.config/google-chrome`
   - or copy: `cp -r $srcdir ~/.config/google-chrome`
3. If you want Chrome to be able to also read Chromiums saved passwords, you need to make sure they use the same master key:

   - Assuming `--password-store=gnome-libsecret`, you’d do:

     ```sh
     secret-tool lookup application chromium | \
         secret-tool store --label="Chrome Safe Storage" application chrome
     ```

Comment: Worked for me with the `snap` directory. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As opposed to the answer that suggested to copy or symlink the `~/.config/chromium` folder to `~/.config/google-chrome` (this actually results in starting Chromium when running the google-chrome executable - I guess, many settings inside the config folder are responsible for this), it is **actually** correct to copy/symlink the `Default` folder inside Chromium's config folder to Chrome's config folder. (Or vice versa, if you will.)

Answer (score 0):

I found on mac that rsync can do the trick it help to copy  all your data .

```
rsync -a ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/ ~/Library/Application\ Support/Chromium
```